# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined (when using require inside require.ensure)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to load a JS file (`mod.js`) dynamically using `require.ensure()`:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    require.ensure([
        "./mod.js" // files that chunk will contain
    ], (require) => {
        var mod = require("./mod.js");
    }, 'mod'); // name of chunk file
})();
```

but I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)
```

which comes from this particular line:

```
var mod = require("./mod.js");
```

which further leads to webpack's `require()` function:

```
// The require function
function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

(...)

// Execute the module function
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

So it appears that `modules[moduleId]` is undefined, but why?

There is **no error when I don't use webpack-dev-server**.

Comment: How is `modules[moduleId]` assigned?

Comment: Webpack's bundle looks more or less like this: `(function(modules) { ... }) ([module#1, module#2, ...])`

Comment: hey! did you ever solve this??

Comment: @ydennis It was almost 2 years ago, but I think I switched to using [import()](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)